# Nginx rewrite and proxy setup

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting

There is a question. when user visit my site with this URL:

mysite.com/proxy/http://example.com/abc.html?q=123

My nginx need the proxy to request this part of the URL(http://example.com/abc.php?q=123).

If it http-response-code is 3XX, and header's location is redircet。com(example) then put the location to `mysite.com/rd.php?u=redirect.com`.

response code is 200, then get the content to `mysite.com/rd.php`. would anyone like to help me to solve this?

Comment: What config have you come up with?

Comment: location ~*  /proxy/(http:/.*)  {  
   proxy_pass http://$1?$args;  
   proxy_redirect  ~*(.*)  http://mysite/rd.php?q=$1;   
  }

Comment: please post it in question and not in comments